# ios - respondsToSelector always false with custom delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols, respondstoselector

I was playing around with MKMap and some custom delegate it's not working here and i really don't know why :/

Here's my code :

**LocationViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)didReceiveLocation:(CLLocation *)location;

@end

@interface LocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<LocationViewDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)sendLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

**LocationViewController.m**

```
[...]
- (IBAction)sendLocation:(id)sender {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceiveLocation:)]) {
        [_delegate didReceiveLocation:_currentLocation];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"nope");
    }
}
[...]
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <LocationViewDelegate>

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
[...]
- (void)didReceiveLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    _mapView.centerCoordinate = location.coordinate;
}
[...]
```

I'm always getting the "nope" message means that `respondsToSelector` returns NO.
I did pretty the same example a few days ago and everything was fine.

Someone can see where's the problem here ?

Comment: 1. Just to verify, are you first setting your MapViewController as the delegate for the LocationViewController? i.e. in your MapViewController.m: self.locationViewController.delegate = self; 2. You're accessing the delegate property as _delegate. Verify you're synthesising it in LocationViewController.m Just as an aside, I'm presuming your MapViewController owns a LocationViewController instance, if so it's better to set the delegate property in LocationViewController to 'weak' to avoid a circular reference. @property (nonatomic, weak) id<LocationViewDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Actually, in the last practice i did, it was not necessary to do smgt like self.locationViewController.delegate = self. It was working without this. But I just tried to add this line of code in this example and still not working. And yep, all is well synthesising

Comment: Okay i found where the problem came from. You were right about the locationViewController.delegate thing. As my two controllers are 2 differents controllers in a TabBarController, i had to add locationController.delegate = mapController in the AppDelegate

Comment: Ok good, have edited my original answer so please mark as accepted if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your MapViewController as the delegate for the LocationViewController i.e. in your MapViewController.m:

```
self.locationViewController.delegate = self;
```

Just as an aside, I'm presuming your MapViewController owns a LocationViewController instance, if so it's better to set the delegate property in LocationViewController to 'weak' to avoid a circular reference. @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;